# select ajax url based on if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I have two AJAX requests and I want to change the URL of second AJAX based on if the user is admin or not. If the user is not an admin a different URL will be used in the AJAX call. I get an error saying that the URL:abcUrl is undefined. I know I may get down voted for asking such a question,but I really need to update the second ajax URL, and it will be a learning experience for me, since I am new AJAX .Any help is much appreciated.

```
var url;
$.ajax( {
        url: sharepointBaseUrl + "_api/web/currentUser/groups?$select=title",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = data.d.results;
            for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (items[i].Title == adminGroupName) { 
                 self.currentUserIsAdmin(true); 
                 abcUrl="Some Url1";
                }
                else{
                 abcUrl="Some Url2";
                }
           }
        },
        error: function (data) { alert("ERROR: " + data) }
} );

$.ajax( {
    url: sharepointScenarioListUrl + abcUrl,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        items.forEach( function(item) { 
                //some function
        });
    },
    error: function (data) { alert("ERROR: " + data); 
                            console.log(sharepointScenarioListUrl + 
                            abcUrl);console.log(data);
                           }
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe abcUrl is undefined because the second AJAX call is happening before the first one returns; since abcUrl is never initialized in your code, it is undefined. If you want to ensure that the second AJAX call happens only after the first one returns, you could place the second ajax call within the success callback of the first AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks J. Chen, you were right. the second AJAX call executed before the first one. I placed the second AJAX in the success of the first AJAX and it works like it should.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

One simple change can fix this issue:

```
function firstCall()
{
        var url;
    var abcUrl;
        $.ajax( {
                url: sharepointBaseUrl + "_api/web/currentUser/groups?$select=title",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    var items = data.d.results;
                    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if (items[i].Title == adminGroupName) { 
                         self.currentUserIsAdmin(true); 
                         abcUrl="Some Url1";
                        }
                        else{
                         abcUrl="Some Url2";
                        }
                   }
                   secondCall(abcUrl);
                },
                error: function (data) { alert("ERROR: " + data) }
        } );
 }       
        function secondCall(abcUrl)
        {
        $.ajax( {
            url: sharepointScenarioListUrl + abcUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                var items = data.d.results;
                items.forEach( function(item) { 
                        //some function
                });
            },
            error: function (data) { alert("ERROR: " + data); 
                                    console.log(sharepointScenarioListUrl + 
                                    abcUrl);console.log(data);
                                   }
        } );

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Allen, though I have accepted J. Chen's answer both solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery `when` or `deferred` methods.

the pseudo will be like this:

```
//get URL for account type
getAccountURL()
    //when done return URL
    .done(function(url){
        //get sharepoint URL
        getSharePointURL(url)
    };
```